# How to create an image view on iphone from an image that is passed back from a webservice as a byte array

Tags: iphone, image, web-services, uiimage, uikit

I am trying to create a `UIImage` from a `byte array`, which I get from the `web service`. The byte array comes embedded in a XML and in the method

```
 -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{
   }
```

I attach it to `currentElementValue`. Then I convert the `currentElementValue` to `NSData` and then to `image`.

```
 content = currentElementValue;
 NSData * imageData = [content dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
```

Now I don't know how I should attach this to a `UIImageView` and how to diplay it. Also if someone knows, I would be thankful to find out how to save that `image` in a file and to display it from that file.

I'm very sorry if this is a stupid question, but I searched in books and also on google and I didn't find something that would work for me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Set the UIImageView's `image` property:

```
self.imageView.image = image;
```

This assumes that you have created an instance of `UIImageView` either programmatically or using a NIB.

Comment: Thank you. If you know, maybe you could tell me also how to save it in a file and how to display it from that file. :)

Comment: @alin `UIImagePNGRepresentation` or `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` will create an `NSData` representation as the format specified. Then write that data to a file with the appropriate file extension. You can then load that file using an initializer such as `-[UIImage initWithContentsOfFile:]`.

Comment: if you don't mind, I have a last question. Only if you have time. Here is the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13415505/cannot-convert-nsdata-to-image-iphone/13415611#13415611. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

either create a new UIImageView, and add it to the view:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
[imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,w,h)];
[view addSubview:imageView];
```

or use "setImage" on an existing UIImageView

```
[imageView setImage:image];
```