# Cannot convert NSData to Image iphone

Tags: ios, image, cocoa, nsdata, typeconverter

I really don't know why it doesn't convert the `NSData` to `UIImage`. The `NSData` gets saved, but when I debug the program, imagine is 0X0000000000 when converting with imageData.

This is my code:

```
NSArray *pathArr = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                       NSUserDomainMask,
                                                       YES);
NSString *path = [[pathArr objectAtIndex:0]
                  stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"img.data" ];

NSData * imageData = [cerereIndemnizatie.fisier dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[imageData writeToFile:path atomically:YES];

NSData *retrievedData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];

UIImage * imagine = [UIImage alloc] init];
UIImage * imagine = [UIImage imageWithData:retrievedData];
```

The code where I parse the data from the web service. I call `writeDataToFileSystem` my pressing a button

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.183:8002/iDocument.asmx"];

    NSMutableURLRequest * request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                            cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                        timeoutInterval:15.0];


    NSString * parameters = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[self XmlRequest]];
    NSLog(@"Request=%@", parameters);
    NSString * msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [parameters length]];

    [request addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request addValue:@"http://tempuri.org/GetDocumenteByIdXML"  forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [request addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[parameters dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


    NSURLConnection * connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];

    if (connection){
        self.responseData = [NSMutableData data];
    }
}

- (NSString *)XmlRequest
{
    NSString * xml = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:
                      @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
                      "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>"
                      "<soap:Body>"
                      "<GetDocumenteByIdXML  xmlns='http://tempuri.org/'>"
                      "<user>admin_document</user>"
                      "<password>123</password>"
                      "<id>%@</id>"
                      "</GetDocumenteByIdXML>"
                      "</soap:Body>"
                      "</soap:Envelope>",self.index];

    return xml;
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    NSLog(@"Response: %@", [response textEncodingName]);
    [self.responseData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    NSLog(@"connection:DidReceiveData");
    [self.responseData appendData:data];
}

- (void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSString * responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Response string: %@", responseString);
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = NO;

    //to do parseXML
    NSXMLParser * xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:responseData];
    xmlParser.delegate = self;
    BOOL succes = [xmlParser parse];

    if (succes) {
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
    else {
    }
}

- (void) writeDataToFileSystem {
    NSArray *pathArr = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                           NSUserDomainMask,
                                                           YES);
    NSString *path = [[pathArr objectAtIndex:0]
                      stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"img.data" ];

    NSData * imageData = [cerereIndemnizatie.fisier dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [imageData writeToFile:path atomically:YES];

    NSData *retrievedData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];

    //UIImage * imagine = [[UIImage alloc] init];
    //UIImage * imagine = [UIImage imageWithData:retrievedData];

    UIImage * imagine = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:retrievedData];

    //    UIImageView *imgv = [[UIImageView alloc]
    //                         initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 200)];
    //
    //    imgv.image = [UIImage imageWithData:retrievedData];
    //    [self.view addSubview:imgv];

}

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName   namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{

    if (![elementName isEqual:@"DetaliiDocument"])
        return;

    cerereIndemnizatie = [[CerereIndemnizatieDoc alloc] init];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Id"]) {
        cerereIndemnizatie.id = currentElementValue;
    }

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Nume"]) {
        cerereIndemnizatie.nume = currentElementValue;
    }

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"TipDocument"]) {
        cerereIndemnizatie.tipDocument = currentElementValue;
    }

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Fisier"]) {
        cerereIndemnizatie.fisier = currentElementValue;
    }

    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"FormatDocument"]) {
        cerereIndemnizatie.formatDocument = currentElementValue;
    }
    currentElementValue = nil;
}


- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {
    if(!currentElementValue) 
        currentElementValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string];
    else
        [currentElementValue appendString:string];
}


- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"connection:didFailWithError:");
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

Comment: your program is saving the data as a UTF8 string representation. `UIImage` won't recognize this representation.

Comment: @Justin how should I save data? :)

Comment: i used also this method to convert the byte array into nsdata      NSData * imageData = [NSData dataWithBytes:(__bridge const void *)(cerereIndemnizatie.fisier)length:cerereIndemnizatie.fisier.length]; but it doesn't work.

Comment: i don't think there's enough information. there's a ton of stuff in google, e.g.: "NSXMLParser UIImage example"

Answer (score 0):

`imageWithData:` doesn't take some arbitrary data and interpret it as an RGBA uncompressed texture.

It takes a data that contains bytes of a recognized image format (like JPG, PNG, or TIFF), parses those and decompresses the images appropriately.

Comment: the data that i parse is jpeg, that's why i used this method.

Comment: can you post the code of parsed jpeg and if possible jpg (in some awkward cases jpeg and jpg creates problem) ?

Comment: i will post it in a minute, the jpeg file is in byte array on the web service, and i parse that byte array into nsdata and nsdata into uiimage.

Answer (score 0):

The image is encoded in some way (e.g. base64) at the backend, try to discover which encoding is used and decode the image at frontend using the same algorithm. NSUTF8StringEncoding doesn't make sense in this case.